# How to create a tvb range object from userdata in a wireshark lua script

Tags: lua, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I am writing a lua script for dissecting a custom protokol. The Protocoll encodes some data in less than 8Bits. I would like to still highlight the bytes where the data is coming from in wireshark.

If i am using tree:add(Protofield, tvb:range) the bytes are highlighted, as i assume the information witch byte to highlight is coming from the tvbrange.

But if i manipulate the data before i feed it into the tree, as plain int, not as tvb range, the bytes are not highlighted. The tree can not know...

Is there a option to create a range object from plain data?

Or as alternativ: Is there a way to pass the tree:add function which bytes to highlight?

```
local detections = 22;
subsubtree:add_le(TimeLag, tvb_sub_buffer(6,4)) -- is highlighting the bytes
subsubtree:add_le(Detections, detections) -- is NOT highlighting the bytes
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to highlight bytes as well as manipulate the data that comes from those bytes, you can do so using something like the following:

```
subsubtree:add_le(TimeLag, tvb_sub_buffer(6,4))

local detections = manipulate_detections(tvb_sub_buffer(10,2):le_uint())
subsubtree:add_le(Detections, tvb_sub_buffer(10,2)):set_text("Detections: " .. detections)
```

Alternatively, you can format the string further if needed, e.g.:

```
subsubtree:add_le(Detections, tvb_sub_buffer(10,2)):set_text(string.format("Detections: %d", detections))
```

Refer to [Section 11.7 of the Wireshark Developer's Guide](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/lua_module_Tree.html) for more information on adding information to the dissection tree and to [Section 20 - The String Library](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.html) of The Programming in Lua Book for more information on `string.format()` and friends.